# How to check USB HDD temperature?

Tags: 14.04, server, usb, hard-drive, temperature

I installed `hddtemp` and `smartmontools`. I can perfectly see HDD of `/dev/sda` but I can't do the same for `/dev/sdc` which is my USB HDD (sata-usb). What do I need to do?

Commands I tried:

```
$ sudo hddtemp /dev/sda
/dev/sda: HITACHI HTS545016B9A300: 37°C
$ sudo hddtemp /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc: Mass Storage Device: S.M.A.R.T. not available
$ sudo smartctl -i -d sat /dev/sdc
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.19.0-28-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 2.5" HDD MK..52GSX
Device Model:     TOSHIBA MK3252GSX
Serial Number:    19V9C2F6T
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 18370861b
Firmware Version: LV010A
User Capacity:    320,072,933,376 bytes [320 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS (minor revision not indicated)
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Wed Sep 16 20:54:07 2015 EEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
```

edited by request: It's an Ubuntu Server 14.04 x64 headless installation CLI only.

Comment: SMART must not be fully enabled

Comment: I can't help here as I don't know much about this topic, but do you know for sure that there is a temperature sensor in the USB HDD at all? Have you successfully tried it from another OS or can you check it with a data sheet or anything like that?

Comment: Yes. It is my old HDD I used to have it in my former laptop, now plugged in via USB/sata case. I can monitor temperature under Windows though.

Comment: What OS are you running and what version? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i in /dev/sd? ; do sudo hddtemp sata:$i; done
```

Comment: One line or two about what your code does would be nice.